# Creating a View using a query created by sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, view, dynamic-sql

I posted a question about creating a dynamic sql statement and got the following code which fulfills this task:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(MAX)
Set @DynSQL = ''

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    select name
    from sys.tables
    where name like 'DDOS_WAF_ACCOUNT_%'

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Add the select code.
    Set @DynSQL = @DynSQL + 'Select * from ' + @TableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1
    INTO @TableName

    -- If the loop continues, add the UNION ALL statement.
    If @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Set @DynSQL = @DynSQL + ' UNION ALL '
    END

END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1

Print @DynSQL
exec sp_executesql @DynSQL
```

Now executing this code displays the table which I want to store for later use. I was told that I should use a view that stores these results but I dont know how to do that. Can I create a view that is populated by this dynamic sql statements and sotre it for repeated use?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - expanding on your original script, the following checks to see if the view already exists (and if it does, checks to see if the view definition will be changing).  There isn't much sense in dropping the view and recreating it if it isn't really changing.  If the view already exists and the new view will be different, then the current view is dropped.

The script may need a little 'clean-up'

```
/*
--initially create 2 tables and run the script code
CREATE TABLE dbo.xx_table01 (col1 int)
CREATE TABLE dbo.xx_table02 (col1 int)

--add another table and run the script code
CREATE TABLE dbo.xx_table03 (col1 int)

--add another table and run the script code
CREATE TABLE dbo.xx_table04 (col1 int)

--add another table and run the script code
CREATE TABLE dbo.xx_table05 (col1 int)
*/
--
DECLARE @CurrentView nvarchar(MAX) = null
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @DynDROP nvarchar(MAX) = 'DROP VIEW XX_VIEW'
SET NOCOUNT ON
Set @DynSQL = 'CREATE VIEW XX_VIEW AS '

set @CurrentView = (select VIEW_DEFINITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' and TABLE_NAME='XX_VIEW')

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where 
    TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND
    TABLE_NAME like 'xx_table%'

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @SchemaName, @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Add the select code.
    Set @DynSQL = @DynSQL + 'Select * from ' + @SchemaName +'.' + @TableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1
    INTO @SchemaName, @TableName

    -- If the loop continues, add the UNION ALL statement.
    If @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Set @DynSQL = @DynSQL + ' UNION ALL '
    END

END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1

IF @CurrentView = @DynSQL 
    PRINT 'VIEW IS THE SAME, NEW VIEW WASN''T CREATED'
ELSE
    BEGIN
        if @CurrentView is not null
        BEGIN
        print @DynDROP
            exec sp_executesql @DynDROP
        END
        PRINT @DynSQL
        exec sp_executesql @DynSQL
    END
```